# Thunderbolt-ethernet cable heats up MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, thunderbolt, ethernet, temperature

I recently bought a thunderbolt-ethernet cable because my university only provides internet access via ethernet, and I have a MacBook Air. The cable works pretty well, except that it really heats up my laptop (particularly the region around the top of the keyboard). Any idea how I can avoid this, if at all? Also, does a USB-ethernet cable also do this?

Comment: What about buying a cheap wifi router, hiding the network and adding a password.

Answer (score 1):

The USB-C gigabit adapters and thunderbolt adapters do run hot. I haven’t found any that do not. Older USB A ones run slower and cooler. Best is to use WiFi as that is the most power efficient adapter for the Air and MacBook line.

Comment: Hmm, so switching to a USB cable won't be beneficial, I suppose?

Comment: The older ones, yes. The new ones, probably not. I use th Belkin USB-C model on my MacBook and it gets pretty toasty. I get much better battery run time on wifi and just as good performance with 802.11ac when the link is above 350 Mbps